# Cone angle conditions on negatively curved surfaces

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geometric-topology

If I glue together hyperbolic triangles along geodesics to get a surface $S$ with negative curvature why do I need to make sure that all the vertices have cone angle at least $2\pi$? Don't I already know that the curvature is negative?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: No, you do not know this: you know this only away from the vertices.

Comment: The point is that $S$ has negative curvature if and only if all the vertices have cone angle at least $2\pi$.

Comment: So away from the cone points I have either points with a totally geodesic neighbourhood or two half totally geodesic disks glued along a geodesic arc in each case they have curvature -1. For the cone points should I take like a small polygon around it and use Gauss-Bonnet to show that I have positive curvature? (Thanks for the comment).

Comment: @Kyle1978: There are different viewpoints on what constitutes curvature for singular surfaces. One viewpoint is that the curvature function is actually a distribution, in which case, yes, Gauss-Bonnet is the way to convince yourself that they curvature will be positive at the vertices where the total angle is $<2\pi$.